# Found this line of code in javascript. What kind of encryption is it?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode this strange Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045701/decode-this-strange-javascript)

```
<script>
[]['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65']('%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%70%72%6f%74%6f%63%6f%6c%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%68%74%74%70%3a%27%29%26%26%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%6f%73%74%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%2d%68%65%6c%70%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29%29%7b%7d%65%6c%73%65%28%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%72%65%66%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29'))()
</script>
```

What kind of encryption method will encrypt javascript above?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "obfuscation" (not "encryption").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first bit of "encryption" appears to be hex ASCII codes:

```
\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72
```

becomes

```
constructor
```

Try `man ascii` for the decryption key.

The second bit of "encryption" also appears to be hex ASCII codes:

```
%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e...
```

becomes

```
if(~location...
```