# Which format/language is this?

Tags: javascript

I was thinking to secure my web pages and found this method somewhere. Only thing I know that this string was in a Javascript/jQuery file.

```
[]['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65']('%69%66%28%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%70%72%6f%74%6f%63%6f%6c%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%68%74%74%70%3a%27%29%26%26%7e%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%6f%73%74%2e%69%6e%64%65%78%4f%66%28%27%74%65%6d%70%6c%61%74%65%2d%68%65%6c%70%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29%29%7b%7d%65%6c%73%65%28%6c%6f%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%2e%68%72%65%66%3d%27%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%67%6f%6f%67%6c%65%2e%63%6f%6d%27%29'))()
```

I know this is written using urldecode

```
[]['constructor']['constructor'](self['unescape']('if(~location.protocol.indexOf('http:')&&~location.host.indexOf('template-help.com')){}else(location.href='http://www.google.com')'))()
```

But how do I implement this in my web pages?

***UPDATE:***

Only thing i learned yet is that placing that code in a single line in last of the jquery or javascript file works. But why that code is executing before page loading... I dont know.

Comment: Try to learn Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

Comment: seems a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045701/decode-this-strange-javascript

Comment: Irony: i was on that page for atleast half an hour. I want how to implement it! not what is it written! Thankyou.